# Serial Driver start_tx() Operation Called Twice for a Single Write

Tags: linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver

Under what circumstances can the uart_ops.start_tx() operation be called twice in rapid succession on a linux 2.6 serial driver?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no issue calling it in rapid succession any number of times.  If done by competing processors, `start_tx()` does a spinlock on `port->lock`.  If done sequentially, the uart-specific driver checks to see if it has already been started.  (From `linux-2.6.27.8/drivers/mmc/card/sdio_uart.c`):

```
    if (!(port->ier & UART_IER_THRI)) {
            port->ier |= UART_IER_THRI;
            sdio_out(port, UART_IER, port->ier);
    }
```

From a higher-level perspective, the serial core checks to see if the transmitter is already started, as well as for appropriateness of starting it (`linux-2.6.27.8/drivers/serial/serial_core.c`):

```
static void __uart_start(struct tty_struct *tty)
{
        struct uart_state *state = tty->driver_data;
        struct uart_port *port = state->port;

        if (!uart_circ_empty(&state->info->xmit) && state->info->xmit.buf &&
            !tty->stopped && !tty->hw_stopped)
                port->ops->start_tx(port);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working in this area on an older kernel, 2.6.10.  I too have seen 2 (or more) calls to the driver's start_tx function given one supposed 'write' by user space.  Via stty, I turned off any 'opost' in the tty layer.  After that, I saw only a single start_tx for each write.  I suspect that the line discipline layer is adding calls to start_tx.

Anecdotal I know, but thought it might help.